# Configuration file naming and location conventions

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, bash

I'm creating a utility program called `zapboot` in response to a question I read a few days ago but can't find anymore. The basic function is to reboot faster back into Ubuntu. I need a configuration file to hold the old GRUB_TIMEOUT=10 and the new GRUB_TIMEOUT=00. These values can be changed by user.

At this point how it technically works is a WIP (Work In Progress) but what would you recommend for the directory where the configuration file is stored according to conventions / industry standards ie `~/`? Additionally, what should the file name be according to conventions / industry standards ie `zapboot.conf.d`?

I hope to use a directory name and file name that provides the shortest learning curve.

Comment: Please split off your "bonus" questions to separate posts.

Comment: Seems configuration files go in `/etc`. The main file could be `/etc/zapboot.conf` and there could be a directory `/etc/zapboot.conf.d` for users to add their own additional configuration files

Comment: To replace `set timeout=10` using `sed` is basic... `sudo sed -i 's/set\ timeout=10/set\ timeout=00/' /boot/grub/grub.cfg` if you are sure that is what you want to do!

Comment: @muru I've deleted the bonus questions. I saw that style somewhere before but down votes show it breaks the standards in AskUbuntu.

Comment: @Zanna ty for `sed` instructions... so simple yet so powerful! I have some scripts in `/usr/local/bin` already and might start there for configuration files and move them where you suggest if project succeeds.

Comment: Multiple unrelated questions do break the Q&A format somewhat. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/270345

Comment: I thought it was making the question too large? They weren't unrelated questions they were the next steps in `zapboot` development, ie bypassing BIOS POST and going straight to grub was the second step. Zanna has solved the first step though--changing grub 10 second countdown timer to 0 seconds.

Comment: @Kazwolfe Thanks for edit. I've implemented the first step with `zapboot` and indeed `Startup Applications` accepts `sudo sed...` command to reset grub timeout to 10 seconds. Next step to call MBR (grub boot) direct from Ubuntu will be posted in a new question after I get starter assembly code of the net.

Comment: They're unrelated in the sense that what you name your config file has nothing to do with editing GRUB's files.

Comment: @muru I see that now. My head was wrapped up in too many project details at one time.

Answer (score 2):

I've no official standards to show for this, but:

- System-wide configuration that should only be edited by a superuser should be in `/etc`. In this, I mostly second [Zanna's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/834462/configuration-file-naming-and-location-conventions#comment1274063_834462):

  > The main file could be `/etc/zapboot.conf` and there could be a directory `/etc/zapboot.conf.d` for users to add their own additional configuration files

  - You could omit the `conf` for the directory (see, for example, `/etc/logrotate.d`, `/etc/pam.d`, etc.)
- Per-user configuration that can be edited by users should be in their home directories, and if you want to be nice about it, should be in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`, following [the XDG Base Directory Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). So your config files would be in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/zapboot`.

  - If `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is unset or empty, default to `~/.config`, so your config files would be in `~/.config/zapboot`.
  - Do read the specification - it's useful for planning out your directory layout

Related:

- [Why do some applications use ~/.config/appname for their config data while others use ~/.appname? - Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24347/70524)

Comment: I'm guilty of putting the cart in front of the horse. `zapboot` phase one (set grub timeout to zero) is complete with no configuration files. They will probably come at the end of development. The program resides in `/usr/local/bin/zapboot` because I didn't want to mess up `/etc`. Phase two--assembler program called `loadmbr` to bypass BIOS POST and boot grub directly from Ubuntu is now under way :) +1 for great answer that helps everyone. I'll wait a couple of days to see if others post answers and then check solved.